# .Net Framework 3.5 reflection issues

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

I'm using reflection to invoke a method from a dll, below the source code

```
ConfigurationObjectsImport configurationObjectsImport;

Assembly asm;
asm = Assembly.LoadFrom("AssemblyName.dll");
object obj;
Type TYP;
TYP = asm.GetType("CustomImport.Import");
obj = Activator.CreateInstance(TYP);
MethodInfo methodInf = obj.GetType().GetMethod("ExecImport");
object[] args = new object[1];
args[0] = configurationObjectsImport;
methodInf.Invoke(obj, args);
```

The class ConfigurationObjectsImport is duplicated in both current project and in dll with the same space name, but methodInf.Invoke(obj, args); throw an exception "cannot convert type Phenix_Import_Commun.Domaine.ConfigurationObjectsImport to type Phenix_Import_Commun.Domaine.ConfigurationObjectsImport".

Comment: If the types are in different assemblies, they are *not* the same type, even if they have the same name.

Comment: Why would you have a class with the exact same namespace in a dll AND in your project? That doesn't make any sense.

Comment: @bc004346 it does make sense if you think they're treated the same by the framework.  its a common misconception that if the types look the exact same that they are the same.

Comment: You would have to get type definition for `ConfigurationObjectsImport` from the assembly as well.

Comment: @Amy, no I certainly would not expect the type with the same name to be treated the same when taken from the project and a DLL. What I don't understand is why would you want to have a class defined in a DLL and your project, while keeping the same class name and namespace. I know with `ananoymous` types those get to reuse the same definition even if you define it twice, but this example kinda puzzles me

Comment: Im using reflection to remove dependencie between my project and the dll . and i need to passe a complexe object  to the invoked methode.

Comment: @bc004346 i'm saying its a common misconception.  I did not base my comment on what *you* would expect.  It's obvious from the question that the OP thinks the two types are the same because they look precisely the same.

Comment: @SoufianeToumlal So basically you both want a dependency (being able to create the object) and don't want it? You might want to move that object to a separate assembly. You will need to reference it from both.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am assuming that configurationObjectsImport is of type `Phenix_Import_Commun.Domaine.ConfigurationObjectsImport` from the executing assembly, but that `CustomImport.Import.ExecImport` is expecting a type of the same name and namespace from `AssemblyName.dll`.  These are two different types that happen to have the same name (which is very undesirable).

If you really have two different types in two different assemblies with the same name, and you want to do this and/or don't have the ability to change this, you will need to create a `Phenix_Import_Commun.Domaine.ConfigurationObjectsImport` object using reflection from `AssemblyName.dll` and pass that in.

If on the other hand, you intend for them to be the same type, you will need to define that type in an assembly that is common to both assemblies (either a 3rd assembly that defines the type, or the executing assembly if `AssemblyName.dll` references it) and only have one type definition of that name.

Comment: thanks i will use a 3rd assembly that defines the type used by ddl and my project